# Accurately passing the player's relative position into AGAL

Tags: 3d, fragment-shader, stage3d, 3dcamera

I'm trying to develop a fragment shader that fades to 0 where the face normals are perpendicular to the direction of the player 'camera'. (This is for spherical planet atmospheres; I want them to fade at their outer extent).

I have the game set up so that the player is always at 'universe position' 0, 0, 0 and all objects have their transform.matrix3Ds translated around the player as it moves.

I should point out that I have multiple shaders working fine, some including mixing textures, interpolating between 2 models and specular shading; THIS problem, though, has me beat.

I've been thinking that the fragment shader needs to know the direction to the player (so that it can dot product between the current face normal and the player direction). But, it also needs to have the model's 'current' vertex position (ie, the vertex output position the shader is currently drawing) added onto the inverse player camera direction; that way the direction to the camera from that model surface location will be correct.

Well, apparently not. (I could explain what I've been doing, but I can sense people ignoring this question already...). Can anybody tell me HOW I can correctly calculate the direction to the player, given that I also need to include (I THINK) the fact that the model's vertex positions are 'offset' from the model's central position? This has been doing my head in!

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Here's the relevant AS3 code followed by the AGAL:

```
// invMatrix is a cloned and inverted copy of the Planet object's transform.matrix3D...
// .deltaTransformVector ONLY uses the matrix3D's rotation to rotate a vector3D...
var tempVector:Vector3D = invMatrix.deltaTransformVector(transform.matrix3D.position);
tempVector.normalize();
context3D.setProgramConstantsFromVector(Context3DProgramType.VERTEX, 5, Vector.<Number>([-tempVector.x, -tempVector.y, -tempVector.z, 0]));
context3D.setProgramConstantsFromMatrix(Context3DProgramType.VERTEX, 7, rotMatrix, true);
... other constants set here ...
context3D.setVertexBufferAt(3, mesh.normalsBuffer, 0, Context3DVertexBufferFormat.FLOAT_3);
```

In the vertex shader:

```
"m44 v3, va3, vc7 \n" + // passed rotMatrix is used to rotate the face normals
"dp3 v4, vc5, va3 \n" + // put the dot product of the normalised, rotated camera position and the rotated normal in v4
```

Then, in the fragment shader:

```
"mul ft0, ft0, v4 \n" + // multiply the sampled texture in ft0 by the passed dot product in v4
```

But this is all making for some weird rendering behaviour, where half of the atmosphere appears drawn, depending on your position relative to the planet. Baffling. Any help well appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you need to find vector from vertex to some point in space? If so, you just need to work in one frame, say in world frame. For that you need to know the desired position in world space and you need to convert your vertices to world space (just multiply by model matrix).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't go into too much detail above, sorry, but what you describe is what I'm doing. I'm passing the object's inverse position into the fragment shader. I'm also passing in the object's rotation matrix and rotating the vertex positions with that. I then add the rotated vertex position to the inverse object position. This should give me the direction to the camera from the fragment being calculated by the shader, but what I'm seeing rendered doesn't look how I expect. It looks like more of the atmosphere is being 'drawn' at the top and bottom of the model. Any ideas?

Comment: That's seems correct. But let me clarify some steps.
1. You need to make such calculations in vertex shader. Why did you pass objects inverse position to fragment shader? And why inverse?
2. You mention that you pass rotation matrix. In fragment shader too? Your object does't translates?

Comment: I pass the model view matrix (its combined translation, scale and rotation) to register vc0. I have tried transforming the model's vertex buffer by that register (as you say, this is done in the vertex shader) and then passing the result to the fragment shader, but that didn't seem to work either. I'll try that again and see how I get on. I'm doing the dot product calculation in the fragment shader because I'm using that to determine how MUCH of the sampled texture is drawn at that pixel.

Comment: So, you know the direction of the camera in world space. And you need to take dot product of normal with this direction. You can do it in vertex shader by transforming normal to world space, but it a bit complicated because you have translation and scale. The better approach is to transform camera direction into object space in application and use this value to dot product with normal. The result should be passed to fragment shader.

Comment: But if I calculate the dot product in the application, I would only be using one normal. To achieve the fading I want, surely I need to calculate the dot product in the fragment shader, using each face's normal so that different dot products are produced...

Comment: Sorry - I think I know what you mean now: Pass the transformed camera direction into the shader and dot product with the face normal in the vertex shader. The question then is: How do I transform the camera direction to the object space? It's inverse rotation matrix? And do I still need to add in the individual position of each pixel, relative to the object's centre coordinates?

Comment: Yes, I mean passing camera to shader. Yes, you need inverse matrix. If your matrix contains rotation, scale, translation then inverse is bit complicated. But there's invert() method in Matrix3D class. If you consider only camera direction then you don't need take positions into account.

P.S.: If you post simplified minimalist code it would be much simpler to explain all this stuff.

Comment: I have added the relevant parts of the code. I will keep trying variations of the above. I've tried NOT rotating the normal and rotating the passed camera direction. I've tried the opposite. Running out of options...

Answer (score 0):

OK - thanks, Volgogradetzzz, for your reply; you definitely reassured me that I was thinking in the right 'direction'. It ended up being a matter of getting many things correct at the same time. I ended up:
1) passing the relative, UN-rotated camera position to the shader.
2) rotating the vertex AND normal buffers in the vertex shader, by the object's rotation matrix (which includes the scale, but NOT the positional translation)
3) finally, the key thing was SUBTRACTING the rotated vertex position from the camera position in the fragment shader
So - it finally works! (Well THAT was a week of my life I'll never get back).